# How to bind MVC .net core checkbox with label as button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have the following code which creates a checkbox that looks like a toggle button.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
 <label asp-for="FlaggedStatus" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
   <input asp-for="FlaggedStatus" type="checkbox"> Flag Address
 </label>
</div>
```

Which looks like this on the form unchecked:

[image]

and then like this when selected:

[image]

The binding works great for saving data. But when I load the form with data already entered, for edit mode, the checkbox is selected in the background, but the button does not show as filled in. So how do I bind it so the button will show as toggled on when the checkbox data is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggle uses the `active` css class on the parent `label`. Your going to have to use some inline logic:

```
<label asp-for="FlaggedStatus" class="btn btn-outline-danger @(Model.FlaggedStatus ? "active")">
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Just needed to add :"" to like @(Model.FlaggedStatus ? "active":"")